# Как установить правильную связь между таблицами?

Tags: php, yii2, table

Работаю с Yii2. Создал две таблицы Blog и BlogComment.

Поля таблицы **Blog**:
**id | title | text**

Поля таблицы **BlogComment**:
**id | blog_id | username | text**

Создал в моделях соответствующие связи:

```
class Blog extends ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'blog';
    }

    public function getBlogсomment() {
        return $this->hasMany(Blogcomment::className(), ['blog_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

И в модели BlogComment:

```
class Blogcomment extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function TableName() {
        return 'blogcomment';
    }

    public function getBlog() {
        return $this->hasOne(Blog::className(),['id' => 'blog_id']);
    }
}
```

В контроллере пытаюсь связаться с таблицами:

```
$query = Blog::find()->with("Blogcomment")->all();
```

В результате выдает ошибку:

> Invalid Argument – yii\base\InvalidArgumentException app\models\Blog
> has no relation named "Blogcomment". ↵ Caused by: Unknown Method –
> yii\base\UnknownMethodException Calling unknown method:
> app\models\Blog::getBlogcomment()

В чем я ошибаюсь? Как заставить работать связь?

Comment: А если `->with("blogcomment")` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, такая же ошибка, только с маленькой буквы: Calling unknown method: app\models\Blog::getblogcomment()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте русское `с` на латинское `c` в:

```
getBlogсomment
```

Comment: Да, похоже, помогло. Спасибо!